# div positioning and responsive web design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, positioning

i apologise if this seems like a stupid question but...

I am trying to position divs beside one another but the catch is, the divs are of different height and width. What i would like is to have these divs sit together so there is no white space (besides margins or padding) Also trying to code this website so it can be responsive and so far i can only have my divs align in grid formation... i am sure i seen some Jquery which vertically aligned divs but for the life of me i can't find it.

[example](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v69/idontknowwhentoshutup/example_zps32c48323.png)

what i have at the moment are all the divs aligned using a responsive grid technique found here: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Comment: Hi, you should be able to post your code or create a jsfiddle  showing what you are trying to do - there's no rep restriction on that.  Take a look at the help to see how to format the code text when you post and someone will be able to help you.  Good luck =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Packery](https://github.com/metafizzy/packery). The Packery website is down at the moment but you can still get the code from [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/metafizzy/packery).

Comment: Masonry! that is it! thank you so much - i couldn't for the life of me remember what it was called.